# Los datos seleccionados en v-select llegan null a Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js

Estoy v-select el cual lo lleno de esta manera :

```
              <v-select name="usuarios[]" multiple v-model="usuarios_seleccionado"
          :options="usuarios" 
          :value="usuarios.id" 
          :required="!usuarios_seleccionado"
          label="fullname"
          >
          </v-select>
```

Se llena correctamente y funciona correctamente, pero cuando escojo sea 1 o mas opciones y lo envio de esta manera a Laravel(parte del codigo):

```
        formData.append("mis_usuarios", this.usuarios_seleccionado);

        axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url:"/registrar_propiedad",
        data: formData,
         headers: {
        },
```

De esa manera lo envio a Laravel, cabe recalcar que no es el único campo del formulario y los otros campos de cajas de texto me llegan bien, pero lo seleccionado del v-select me llega como string "object Object" y he tratado de leerlo pero se me hace imposible, me da una mano ?

Comment: ¿Estás ocupando la librería `vuetify`? Lo pregunto porque estás ocupando la etiqueta `<v-select>`

Comment: instale v-select sin vuetify